# How can I send the output of external programs to a Perl socket?

Tags: perl, sockets

I have just started to learn socket programming using Perl. Is there a method to send the output (STDOUT)  data/images from already running scripts/tools using Perl socket programming?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your *existing* script dumps its output to the console (`STDOUT`) you can just redirect it using [netcat](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/) (see [`nc(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nc)):

On the server:

```
server-host:~$ nc -l -p 3232 > file.txt
```

On the client:

```
client-host~$ perl -e 'printf( "Hello %s\n", "world" )' | nc server-host 3232
```

The choice if the port (3232) is of course arbitrary, but on Unix it should be greater then 1024 for you to be able to bind it without root privileges.

#### Edit:

How about this then:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;

my $usage = "Usage: $0 <host:port> <prog>\n";
my $hp = shift @ARGV or die "$usage";
my $prg = shift @ARGV or die "$usage";
my ($host,$port) = split ":", $hp;

defined $host or die "$usage";
defined $port or die "$usage";

exec "$prg @ARGV | nc $host $port" or die "can't execute $prg\n";
```

Comment: Thanks Nikolai: Can you also please give me some brief to automate this task.

Comment: Thanks for this, but this is doing the same thing, after executing command the session breaks and for sending another command i have to again open the server.